# Is it valid to ask similar questions, one requesting RAW and the other XP?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, rules-as-written

Related to [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2697/4089).

I am wondering if it would be excessive to split up questions requesting RAW answers and actual experience answers. One example would be if I took [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19221/4089) and reworded another question modeled after it looking for essentially the same thing except instead of the RAW constraint seeking advice from other DMs for how they handle it.

Comment: That might not be the best example, since as currently written it's asking for both RAW answers and DMs' rules-of-thumb (i.e., experience).

Comment: I edited it to reflect the answer by @mxyzplk

Comment: Oh! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it would be excessive.

We don't need to ask questions from N different perspectives.  The point is to ask a question and have N different perspectives reflected in the answers, which are then voted and accepted.  Breaking it up does, in fact, work against the general mechanic of the SE.

People need to stop with the "RAW question" vs "other question" thing.  It's fine to say you're especially interested in RAW in the question, but in many cases that is a vain and sometimes technically incorrect constraint anyway.  Just ask the questions and vote up the helpful answers.  If helpfulness, to you, requires a degree of RAW then vote how the spirit moves you. As will others.

Comment: It does seem to be something common on this SE (RAW vs. XP), but we're also dealing with something that's commonly 'interpreted' and 'houseruled.' I like your idea of simply leaving the constraint out though, with perhaps encouragement toward one's preference.

Comment: Yeah.  Keep in mind questions aren't really "all yours," hence the OP accept functionality being totally separate from the community voting functionality.